# How do I pull a specific bit of information from html to a python webscraper?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

*Ok, decided to edit this real quick and just include my entire script here.*

This is my first 'real world' application using python, or, for that matter, any programming language. 
I've built a basic web scraper using a tutorial I found and am trying to add information and build upon it to create something more useful than it is. 
The problem I am having is that the information gathered has been relatively easy to get to so far, but now I am stuck on pulling the price out of this bit of code here, into my python script.

I can get the price from here, but it's in a terrible formatting with characters and whitespace that I can't seem to figure out how to strip, which completely ruins my .csv file at the end of the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

my_url = "https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?
Tpk=graphics%20cards"

#Grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)

#Reading uCLient and saving contents as a variable called page_html (it is 
raw html code)
page_html = uClient.read()

#Close the web connection to uCLient
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#Grabs graphics card containers / each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

filename = "products.csv"

f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "Brand, Product Name, Price, Shipping\n"

f.write(headers)


for container in containers:

    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

    title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    price_container = container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-current"})
    price = price_container[0].text.strip('|')

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

    print("Brand: " + brand)
    print("Product name: " + product_name)
    print("Price: " + price)
    print("Shipping: " + shipping)

    f.write(brand + "," + product_name.replace(",","|") + "," + price + "," 
    + shipping + "\n" )


f.close()
```

The bit of html when running shipping_container looks like this:

```
<li class="price-current">
   <span class="price-current-label">
   <a class="membership-info membership-popup" data-neg-popid="MembershipPopup" 
      href="javascript:void(0);" name="membership" style="display: inline"><span 
      class="membership-icon"></span><span style="display: none">|</span></a>
   </span>$<strong>249</strong><sup>.99</sup> <a class="price-current-num" 
      href="https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?
      Item=N82E16814150795&amp;buyingoptions=New&amp;ignorebbr=1">(10 Offers)</a>
   <span class="price-current-range">
   <abbr title="to">–</abbr>
   </span>
</li>
```

As you have probably figured out by now, what I want is for print(price) to display only 249.99. What am I screwing up here, or missing?

This is what gets imported to my actual .csv file '|\n$249.99\xa0(10 Offers)\n\n–'

or

---

|
$249.99(19 offers)

-

---

Here's the [link](https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20cards) I'm working with.

Guys, to be honest, I'm not looking for a "do it for me" kind of answer but rather something I can learn from. I'm just trying to figure out why it is that I get this jumbled mess and why

```
>>> price = price_container[0].findAll('li',{'/span':'strong'})
>>> price
```

OR

```
>>> price = price_container[0].findAll('li',{'strong':'strong'})
>>> price
```

returns nothing, but without error...

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: BeautifulSoup4.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code for scraping the data from the sample HTML that you've provided:

```
# We are using BeautifulSoup library for scraping.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == "__main__":

    temp = 'REPLACE THIS STRING WITH THE ABOVE SAMPLE HTML'

    # For using this in the real website, you can iterate over the lists with class 'price-current'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(temp, 'html.parser')
    dollars = soup.find("strong").text
    cents = soup.find("sup").text
    print(dollars + cents)
```

Here are some cool libraries, which you can use in your scraping project:

1. [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
2. [Scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/)
3. [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Note: You should always check if it is legal to scrape data from that website.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'm going to have to get back to work and see if I can make this work out. 
Sidenote: I had no idea that it COULD be possible for web scraping to be illegal. Do you have any info on that? Why would simply pulling information that is already public cause an issue?

Comment: It could be illegal (not for all websites though). eg. LinkedIn. You should read the privacy policy of that website if you don't want to get into trouble.

Comment: Oh, okay, scraping social media's such as that I could understand.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. It will give you only the price in a much cleaner way. Btw, consider the `html_elem` in the below scraper is the alternative name of `html elements` you pasted above.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_elem,"lxml")
print(''.join([item.text.strip() for item in soup.select("strong,sup") if item.text.split()]))
```

Result:

```
249.99
```

Comment: I actually forgot I had a posting here and needed to update it. I got an answer from Reddit, and the one that works best so far is pretty close to yours. 
Now I&#39;m rrying to undersrand why it is I have to get the price in such a vastly different way than anything else so far.
If I were to guess, the first place I'd start is my extreme lack of understanding anything in HTML